# Stubbing window functions in Jest

Tags: javascript, sinon, jestjs

In my code, I trigger a callback upon "OK" click of a `window.confirm` prompt, and I want to test that the callback is triggered.

In `sinon`, I can stub the `window.confirm` function via:

```
const confirmStub = sinon.stub(window, 'confirm');
confirmStub.returns(true);
```

Is there a way I can achieve this stubbing in Jest?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In jest you can just overwrite them using `global`.

```
global.confirm = () => true
```

As in jest every test file run in its own process you don't have to reset the settings.

Comment: I don't believe it's true that you don't have to reset settings. I just tested this and can confirm that when I set `global.innerWidth`, it persisted across tests.

Comment: With test I mean test files

Answer (score 14):

I just used **Jest mock** and it works for me :

```
   it("should call my function", () => {
      // use mockImplementation if you want to return a value
      window.confirm = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => true)

      fireEvent.click(getByText("Supprimer"))

      expect(window.confirm).toHaveBeenCalled()
}
```

Answer (score 11):

To eliminate the chances that the mocking would leak to other tests, I used a one-time mock:

```
jest.spyOn(global, 'confirm' as any).mockReturnValueOnce(true);
```