# Testing OAuth with Jest

Tags: oauth, jestjs

I'm new to jest. I have created a Vue plugin that wraps the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL.js). I would like to unit test it with Jest. The basic tests are up and running (is the plugin method mounted on the Vue instance, etc.).

I would like to test the actual calls to the authentication service. I'm running into the problem that there is no browser.

> Error: Not implemented: window.open

This is my test code.

```
it('should fail with a useful error when configuration or option settings are not set or are incorrect', () => {
    const azureAuthService = new AzureAuthService()
    const testException = () => {
      azureAuthService.login()
    }
    expect(testException).toThrow(TypeError)
})
```

Any suggestions how to implement this test

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stubbing window functions in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41732903/stubbing-window-functions-in-jest)

Comment: Thx for your respons. This is a solution for stubbing the respons. I want to actually call the external OAuth service and test the different errors it returns. Any suggestions if this can be done and how?

Comment: if you are developer of OAuth provider you write integration tests(and that does not use Jest). if your code consumes OAuth(that I believe is your case) you just mock OAuth service's response and check how do your code behaves.

Comment: After some more digging around I figured out that would be the route :-) Can you point me in the right direction where I can find example jest code that uses the global to set stubs to intercept/set the required values?

Comment: how I see testing that: 1. mocking `window.open`(link in my first comment shows the way). 2. call service's method. 3. ensures that `window.open` has been called with appropriate arguments(expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(.....)). do you ask about such an example? or do you have other vision on how to test it?