# Jest prompt return value

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a function that calls prompt window

```
export const sumOfInputDigits = () => {
  let input = prompt("Enter a 3-digit integer number: ");
  if (/^\d{3}$/.test(input)) {
    //it is a string of 3 digits
    //get array
    let inputArray = input.split("");
    //get sum
    return inputArray.reduce((acc, digit) => {
      return (acc += Number(digit));
    }, 0);
  } else {
    //one or more digits is not a number
    return `${input} is not a 3-digit number`;
  }
};
```

And I want to test this function, is it possible to avoid the prompt window to pop up and not to type any value in it just to have it somehow?
I've been trying already this. Test has passed.

```
jest.spyOn(window, "prompt").mockImplementation(() => "123");
    expect(sumOfInputDigits()).toBe(6);
```

but prompt window still popups.

Comment: [*"By default, `jest.spyOn` also calls the **spied** method."*](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname)

Comment: Prompt window still pops up. Any ideas how to avoid it?

Comment: What do you mean "still"? Did you change anything?

Comment: ```
describe("exercise 3, sum of digits in 3-digit number", () => {
  it("returns 6 for 123 ", () => {
    jest.spyOn(window, "prompt").mockImplementation(() => "123");
    expect(sumOfInputDigits()).toBe(6);
  });
});
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question. But note there's a more architectural solution - don't have the function call prompt, call it with a string you could be from prompt or elsewhere.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41732903/stubbing-window-functions-in-jest